# parse db result by pydantic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Hi i have function that renders template and I want to populate it with data so i query the db and i get list of

```
*sqlalchemy*
[<src.utils.models.case object at 0x22BF6850> , <src.utils.models.case object at 0x22BF6850> ...]
```

And this is a function

```
*fastapi*
@router.get('/rcase')
def case(request: Request, db: orm.Session = Depends(services.get_db)):

    result = services.get_all_cases(db=db)
  
    context = {
        "request":request,
        "cases":result
    }
    return templates.TemplateResponse("case.html", context)
```

how can I use pydantic model to parse this data?

I've tried

```
schemas.Case(**result)
schemas.Case(**result.dict())
[schemas.Case(**x) for x in result]
[schemas.Case(**x.dict()) for x in result]
```

Should I parse model to JSON? and then pass it to pydantic?

When building API I can use response_model but how to parse data that I want to display in server-side rendered template?

Comment: Yeah orm_mode = True

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53414930/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: If you're not using a response model, is there any reason to convert anything to pydantic in this case? Your database library and database will already have made sure that everything is the expected type.